# How do you simulate random selection of an nth visitor without a static counter

Tags: algorithm, random, selection

I need to create a script that prompts every 4th or 9th user as a sampling of users that visit over a day,  but I dont have a way to store a global counter (file system,  memory etc),  is there an algorithm or function that could approximate selection of an nth user?

Or even a probability sampling would work...  Say for 25%

Approximate,  preferbably something with more speed than accuracy

Comment: Is it have to be strictly nth user? Can't you decide to sample a user with probabilty = 1/n? The expected number of sampled users should be the same.

Comment: Probability sampling would work too now that you mention.  What do you suggest?

Comment: Since you mentioned it is an acceptable approach - it fits better as an answer - added it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative could be a probabalistic sampling.

If you want to sample every K'th user (for some specific k), you need to generate a random integer in range `[0,K)` - and sample this user if and only if the generated number is 0 (or any other single number actually).

The *expected* number of sampled users will be the same as you sampled every kth user.

Comment: So... basically just generate an random integer within the range of n I want to select from, and assume the value 0 is selected 25% of the time?

Comment: @qodeninja: In this case, you need to draw a random *double* in range [0,1) - and sample the user if and only if the sampled number is smaller then 0.25. It will give you 25% probability of sampling him.